# Scalable sequential ID generator for related entities using @TableGenerator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, primary-key, scalability

I am writing a web-application where some IDs will be visible to the users in the URL. The application is meant to be used by more users having each an Account. An Account can then have Projects, and each Project has Tasks.

Now, I do not want the users to have their first project created with an ID of 24876 (or whatever a normal generated ID would be), but rather to have a "nice looking" sequential identifier **additionally** to a generated primary key (mainly because it is simpler to manipulate entities that have non-composite identifiers). Let's call these sequential IDs viewIds.

ViewIDs would start at 1 for each different "parent" identifier (for a Project, that would be an Account). The combination (accountId, projectViewId) is unique, as well as (projectId, taskViewId) etc.

My question is: how to generate these viewIds? I was thinking of perhaps using the [TableGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) mechanism, but can this one also be used for non-identifier columns?

Most importantly though, what would be the best way to generate such IDs in an environment where several application servers use the same database (and ideally without the need to have them communicate with eachother directly)? Is there perhaps already an implementation of a TableGenerator or a utility that achieves the above?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, this is the solution I ended up adopting:

instead of relying on Hibernate/JPA to manage these "nice looking" IDs, I chose a database-based approach:

- For each entity with a viewID, I define a trigger that will increment it at each insert, based on the max of the elements within one sequence (e.g. all Tasks for Project 22)
- I also have a multi-unique key constraint on (project_id, naturalId) for those entities like Task.

The one thing I am not sure about is how this would behave in e.g. a master-to-master replication of the database, where both database servers can be used. But for application server replication, this should do the job.